# MasterPage INSIDE iFrame

Tags: asp.net, iframe, master-pages

any remarks? Doesn't seem to be any info around. Doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No remarks. A page that loads correctly with masterpages on its own will definitely load correctly inside an iframe as well, if you use the exact same url. What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: It seems the problem was not related to the MasterPage itself, but to another iFrame contained in the MasterPage. Thank you :)